# Copy CMApplication with PowerShell

Tags: sccm

You can copy an application in the Configuration Manager like this.

[image: Copy Example]

Is this also possible with Powershell? Or are there other ways to copy an application via script?

There are a few Copy-CMxxxxx Cmdlet's, but no Copy-CMApplication :(

thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no simple command for this. You can of course do it in script, because you have all the tools to get the info for any application as well as create a new one, so you can also create a new one that is identical to one you already have. As some stuff is stored in XML form it might not be super straight forward to read out though. Not sure how far you can come without parsing xml